# Why are the values of variables based on timeframe.multiplier being reset in request.security calls?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm writing an intraday-only indicator whose goal is to assign/re-assign the value of certain variables based on the time frame of the active chart. In principle, as the user clicks on a different time frame, the indicator would dynamically adjust to the current time frame. The code below is trivial and was designed simply to illustrate the problem I've run into.

```
indicator(title = 'timeframe.multiplier issue', overlay=true)
int user_input = 4
var int LB     = timeframe.multiplier + user_input 

plot(ta.sma(high,9), color=color.fuchsia,linewidth=3)     // hard coded
plot(ta.sma(high,LB), color=color.black,linewidth=2)      // calculated

hi_1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', high[9],  lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)      
hi_2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '1', high[LB], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)     
plot(hi_1, color=color.yellow,linewidth=3)               // hard coded
plot(hi_2, color=color.white,linewidth=1)                // calculated

// Troubleshooting only: places Debug table in upper right corner
var debug_table = table.new(position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 4)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = debug_table, column = 0, row =  0, text_color=color.white, text_halign=text.align_left, text = "timeframe.multiplier")
    table.cell(table_id = debug_table, column = 0, row =  1, text_color=color.white, text_halign=text.align_left, text = "LB")
    table.cell(table_id = debug_table, column = 1, row =  0, text_color=color.white, text_halign=text.align_right, text = str.tostring(timeframe.multiplier,'#'))
    table.cell(table_id = debug_table, column = 1, row =  1, text_color=color.white, text_halign=text.align_right, text = str.tostring(LB, '#'))
```

Lines 2 & 3 of the code define a lookback variable 'LB' to be equal to the current chart time frame plus some user input =4. Assuming we are on a 5 min chart LB calculates out to 9 (=5 + 4). The next two lines plot an SMA based on the LB=9 parameter using either a hard-coded or calculated version of LB. As expected, using a 5 min chart, the two plots are identical and overlap each other (think black line over thicker fuchsia line.

The problem comes in the remaining lines of the code when I use the same exact approach but replace SMA with a `request.security` function that captures data from the 1 min time frame. As with SMA, in principle the two `request.security` plots should be identical and overlap regardless of whether When LB=9 is hard coded in, or calculated. But this is not the case. The hard coded plot is correct (yellow), the calculated is incorrect (white). To trouble shoot, I included a debug table that prints in the top right of the chart. This confirms that the calculated value of LB is 9, as expected. Thus, LB is calculating properly, but it's as if `request.security` is not recognizing it properly. After some trouble shooting, it seems the problem is that when LB is used in the `request.security` function, it is calculated from the `request.security` time frame (in this case 1 min), NOT the chart time frame (5 min). In the current example that means that when used by `request.security` LB is calculated as 1 + 4, instead of 5 + 4. Note that this pattern held when using other request.security time frames; and yes, this is how it's behaving despite the fact that the debug table shows LB is calculated as expected.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Note: Due to other aspects of the actual script its best that I use  `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` and not other options including `request.security_lower_tf`

[image]